# What was the meaning of the country song in the episode "Aus der Tiefe der Zeit"?

Tags: analysis, soundtrack, tatort

The *Dominik Graf* directed [*Tatort*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0806910/) episode ["Aus der Tiefe der Zeit"](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt2865680/) repeatedly employs a certain country song as in-scene background music at various occasions. More or less anytime when some music plays as part of the scene, it is this song, be it at the party of the *Löwenhof* constructors, *Jansen*'s apartment, the casino where the Croatians meet, and especially most prominently in the *Holzer* villa, when *Peter Holzer* commits suicide and later when *Liz* is arguing with *Ante*, ...

I am unable to find out what the name of this song was, so first of all, **what song was that?** But even more important, **was there any meaning to this song** in relation to the story and its motives, and **what would that be?** The only slight connection I could draw was, that this very Western-style song might just be an allusion to *Magda Holzer*'s past in the *"Annie Oakley Show"* decades ago, but that doesn't hold so strong when the song is used at each and every possible occasion and *Magda*'s past as *"Annie Oakley"* wasn't much significant at all.